# How to create Spring Boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

I have a spring boot application that needs a controller that can handle the following request:

The request is sent by another service through the Post method..

**Headers**

**accept-encoding:** gzip,deflate

**user-agent:** Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)

**connection:** Keep-Alive

**host:** webhook.site

**content-type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**content-length:** 558

**Query strings:**(empty)

**Form values**

**BillNumber:** 41492032464

**BillValue:** 600000.0

**Description:** Description

I have this controller, but my application returns an HTTP Error 406:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bills", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public void createBill(UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
}
```

How should this controller be implemented in my spring boot app?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you more explain ! Do want to khnow how to call a service rest ? or you want to create a service rest witch create a bill ? if yes so can you give your object that you want to send to your service

Comment: simply this is the request that my controller must handle, does not return anything it's void

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear for me but if you use spring boot you can of course create a controller , service and repository or dao.
Indeed, your controller will call your service witch will call the repository.

Let's suppose that you have a client witch call your api.

So the call will look like :

```
// Suppose that is a spring boot project

Class A {

@Autowired 
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public void create(){

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType((MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.add("X-yourCustom-context", "yourCustom");

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(your_service_url)
                    .queryParam("params1", "value".queryParam("params2", value2));
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, null); // if you want to return an objectr you put it rather than the null

}

}
```

**Th service api :**

```
@RestController
public class YourController {
    @Autowired
    private YourService service;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @PostMapping(value = "/bills")
    //@ResponseBody if you do not return any think you can not use it
    // @CrossOrigin if you want to call your reste from an external project like javascript or angular
    //@Transactional you can put it on the top of your service methode
    public void createBill(@RequestParam(value = "params1", required = true) String params1, 
    @RequestParam(value = "params2", required = true) String params2,
    @RequestHeader(value = "X-yourCustom-context", required = true) String yourContxt) throws IOException {

    // You can then convert your x-context to an object that you have already by using objectMapper.readValue
    // Finaly you call you service to create the bill and you passe as params what you get fron the client 
}
}
```

I hope it meets your needs :)